# Shortest path with minimal blue edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph,such that ever $e\in E$ has a color-blue or red.
>
> Given $G$ and some $s,t\in V$ ,find an efficient algorithm that find from all pathes from $s$ to $t$,one with an even amount of red edges,and minimal amount of blue edges.

For the part of the even amount of red edges,I know that I can split the vertices,$v$ to $v_o,v_e$ for odd or even amount of red edges till I reached that vertex.

But I'm not sure,how to do the part with the blue edges?

I could give some weight to the blue edges (and red 0 weight) and use Dijkstra's algorithm,but there is a solution in $O(|E|+|V|)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're thinking Dijkstra's algorithm, then you must think this is a shortest-paths problem.  Do you know any other algorithms for finding shortest paths?

Comment: @D.W. You mean like BFS,DFS?

Comment: This is your exercise, so I'm going to let you figure out how to solve it.  I encourage you to spend some more time on it and see what you can come up with.

Comment: @D.W. ok,but will you give me a hint?do I need to modify BFS/DFS in the solution?

Comment: I think D.W. is pushing you in the right direction. Do not think *what to do* at first glance (e.g., whether to modify BFS/DFS or any other algorithm). Instead recognize the key components of your problem to figure out *how to do it*. D.W. already told you an important one: according to your intuition if you use weights then this problem can be seen as a Shortest Path Problem (SPP). Note however, there is an additional component, and it is that candidates are constrained to have an even amount of red edges. Question is: what SPP algorithm(s) you know that could handle constraints, and *how*?

Comment: @CarlosLinaresLópez I think that changing BFS so that $d[v]$ will be amount of blue edges so far,from $s$ to $v$.

Comment: That is definitely right! What about the constraint?

Comment: @CarlosLinaresLópez The even amount of red edges?Wouldn't what I said about splitting,work?

Comment: That would definitely work for a breadth-first/best-first search. Consider depth-first search algorithms instead for quite a while and note that these algorithms actually traverse paths (as they do not detect duplicates) ... do you really think then that splitting is necessary? I hope you can see now you have two choices here. As you were requested to find an efficient algorithm you can actually return two answers for two different forms of efficiency. Why do not yourself try to write an answer to your own question?